# Why caching service does not cache downloaded app from app store?

Tags: macos, services, cache

I've enabled Caching server on osX server as it has green light. On this stage I downloaded an app from app store but cache tell None in the picture below. Is there something else to configure on this osX server?

[image]

The log in /Library/Server/Caching/Logs/Debug.log says:

```
2015-12-08 10:57:19.989 Request for configuration from http://suconfig.apple.com/resource/registration/v1/config.plist succeeded
2015-12-08 10:57:20.000 Registering with local address: localIPAddress (Masked for security) (100 Mbit/sec wired); on AC power: yes; cache size: ~350 GB; capabilities: im,ns,pc,qp,sc; portable: no
2015-12-08 10:57:20.368 Cleanup succeeded.
2015-12-08 10:57:22.440 Request for registration from https://lcdn-registration.apple.com/lcdn/register succeeded
2015-12-08 10:57:22.440 Got back public IP *.*.*.* (Masked for security)
2015-12-08 10:57:22.451 This server has 0 peers
```

In server log I could see:

```
Dec  8 11:27:40 MyOSXServer AssetCache[94461]: Caching Server started
Dec  8 11:27:40 MyOSXServer AssetCache[94461]: CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/AssetCache/AssetCache.momd/AssetCache-v5.omo'
XServer AssetCache[94461]: Registration succeeded.  Resuming server.
```

There was an update requested on app store for `server.app` on `EL Capitan`, I updated it but nothing happened so far. I receive the below error on `Log` section:

```
'/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/AssetCache/AssetCache.momd/AssetCache-v5.omo'
    XServer AssetCache[94461]: Registration succeeded.  Resuming server.
```

On osX server firewall is set to off. Should I open this port on external firefall (Public IP address) too?

Comment: @Tetsujin I've deleted that I thought its better to ask this on super user.

Comment: AH, OK. No worries then :)